# Cannot change the background of Google charts tables tool

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've looked everywhere, but it can't seem that you can change the background color of the Google charts tables. I've tried modifying the css and changing the javascript properties without success. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the cssClassNames option. Here's how: http://jsfiddle.net/cama8/

```
var cssClassNames = {
    'headerRow': 'italic-darkblue-font large-font bold-font',
    'tableRow': 'beige-background',
    'oddTableRow': 'beige-background',
    'selectedTableRow': 'orange-background large-font',
    'hoverTableRow': '',
    'headerCell': 'gold-border',
    'tableCell': '',
    'rowNumberCell': 'underline-blue-font'};

     var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
     table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, 'cssClassNames': cssClassNames});
```

Comment: The selectedTableRow has no effect, particularly the background-color. Even on your JSFiddle. (I am using Chrome Browser)